# Redirect chat.unix.stackexchange.com to a more useful URL

Tags: feature-request

I think this is a feature request, but it could be a usability bug. I wanted U&L chat so I prepended `chat` to `unix.stackexchange.com` which resulted in `chat.unix.stackexchange.com`. I was redirected to `chat.stackexchange.com` with 47 pages of rooms.

The redirect was not very helpful because it was not clear which of the 920 rooms I should select. The rooms seem to be listed in random order and it was not clear what to do next. At minimum I would have expected the U&L room, `/dev/chat`, to be listed first (or at least on the first page).

Perhaps a redirect should be added that redirects users from `chat.unix.stackexchange.com` to `chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat`.

Comment: I find it rather amusing that jww gets a “New contributor” label with this question ;-). (Yes, I know why, I still find it amusing.)

Answer (score 2):

I mean, it couldn't hurt I guess, but in general trying to get somewhere by guessing a subdomain isn't very reliable. The right way to get to U&L's chat is to click the Stack Exchange logo at the top-right and click the "[chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=unix.stackexchange.com)" link next to the site:

[image]

If you're already on chat, you can use the "site" tab at the top to switch to a site-filtered view.